# object property - Meteor call

Tags: meteor

How to return the value from meteor.call. Please refer the code for more detail.

```
highlightStroke: "rgb(15,138,12)",
data:Meteor.call('dataCallYou', Session.get('areaHome'), function(error,you){
        if(_.isEmpty(you)){
          you=[0,0,0,0]
        }
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Meteor.call`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#Meteor-call) is an **asynchronous task**.

See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)